# Connection problems with Magic Mouse 2 while wifi is on (MBP2012)

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, mouse

I have a modified mbp 2012 with a Samsung 256GB 850 EVO and 16gb ram. I recently upgraded my mouse to a Magic Mouse 2, but so far it isn't the best upgrade ever!

I'm having struggles to connect my mouse after shutdown of the mouse or MBP. I can only reconnect it to bluetooth after disabling wifi.

Are there any solutions to this problem without having to disable anything? I have heard of a possible solution involving  disabling of hotspot with an Iphone, but i have to use that sometimes.

Thanks for reading, and hoping for a reply :-)

Edit: I'm currently running macOs Sierra 10.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the hotspot with an iphone seems like the only option. Had it running for a few months without any problems now.